# Why is it not possible to test HttpContext.Current.Request for null before Application_AquireRequestState?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-application-insights

According to [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.Implementation.HttpContextExtensions.GetRequest](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/42eb04a44bc7f2f015dd760334ada7bfbaf21f49/WEB/Src/Web/Web/Implementation/HttpContextExtensions.cs#L7) it is not (always?) possible to check if `HttpRequest` is null in `HttpContext`:

> // HttpRequest is not available in HttContext till Application_AquireRequestState
>
> // But there is no way to check it; only catch HttpException

Why would that be?

```cs
        public static HttpRequest GetRequest(this HttpContext context)
        {
            // HttpRequest is not available in HttContext till Application_AquireRequestState
            // But there is no way to check it; only catch HttpException
            HttpRequest result = null;
            try
            {
                result = context.Request;
            }
            catch (HttpException exp)
            {
                WebEventSource.Log.HttpRequestNotAvailable(exp.Message, exp.StackTrace);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Wouldn't a simple coalesce also work, e.g.

```cs
var request = HttpContext.Current?.Request;
```

And couldn't I avoid the whole `try-catch` and the `Exception` alltogether?

Answer (score 0):

*Using* `coalesce`   for `httpcontext`
*The property `Current` is used to access the `HttpContext.AddError`, `HttpContext.ClearError` and the `HttpContext.AllErrors` .
With the properties AddError,  AllErrors we can create custom exceptions.*

```
             try
                {
                    object ss = System.Web.HttpContext.Current ?? false;
                    if ((Boolean)ss)
                    {
                        //Some code....
                        //.......
                    }
                }
     catch (HttpException exp)
                {
                    WebEventSource.Log.HttpRequestNotAvailable(exp.Message, exp.StackTrace);
                }
```

*passing  boolean value in case of null*
[image]

*passing string in case of null*
[image]

*you can check* [Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) *and* [HttpContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx)

Comment: How does this explain the question? If at all, it would confirm that a coalesce would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, coalesce will work for HttpContext, 
object obj= `HttpContext.Current.Session["something"] ?? false;`